# tkinter entry bg and state

Tags: python, tkinter

What can I do to change the bg color of my entry when the state is readonly.

```
    self.v6 =StringVar()
    self.txtpic6=Entry(self.root,bg="#cd853f", textvariable=self.v6,state="readonly",justify="center")
    self.txtpic6.place(relx=0.87,rely=0.4,relwidth=0.04,relheight=0.06)
```

In this code, the bg color isn't working.but when I remove the state attribute , the bg color works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `readonlybackground` should help. For example:

```
self.txtpic6=Entry(self.root,bg="#cd853f", textvariable=self.v6,state="readonly",justify="center", readonlybackground='red')
```